# Apache2 redirects all requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache2, amazon-vpc

I have an Apache setup in AWS in a private VPC. It is configured to serve on 3 ports: 80, 443 and 1025.

Port 80 is just for redirection, my .htaccess in /var/www/ looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://my.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Which works fine, everything that comes in on port 80 gets redirected to port 443.

Port 443 is working find with its certificate.

The problem I'm trying to resolve is to separate or segregate the web site. It will be serving regular web pages in the following structure:

`/var/www/[site-code-here]`

but there's a directory there, named `/var/www/api` that can't be exposed to the world, but needs to be exposed to AWS api gateway. So what i did was to create 2 virtualHosts, one on port 443 to serve the web pages (blocking access to the api folder explicitly), and another on port 1025 to serve the API with document root on `/var/www/api/` (both using the same certificates) like so:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>


<VirtualHost _default_:1025>
  ServerAdmin connect@my.domain.com
  ServerName https://my.domain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/api
    <Directory />
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/api>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_apigw.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel trace8

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_apigw.log combined

    SSLEngine on

  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/my.domain.com.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/my.domain.com.key

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

    SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
        SSLHonorCipherOrder On
        SSLCompression off
        # Add six earth month HSTS header for all users...
        # Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000"
        # If you want to protect all subdomains, use the following header
        # ALL subdomains HAVE TO support HTTPS if you use this!
        # Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000 ; includeSubDomains
        SSLCipherSuite 'EDH+CAMELLIA:EDH+aRSA:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH:+CAMELLIA256:+AES256:+CAMELLIA128:+AES128:+SSLv3:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!DSS:!RC4:!SEED:!ECDSA:CAMELLIA256-SHA:AES256-SHA:CAMELLIA128-SHA:AES128-SHA'
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  ServerAdmin connect@my.domain.com
  ServerName my.domain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ### Block access via 443 to the API
#   <Directory /var/www/api/datastreams/>
#       order deny,allow
#       Deny From All
#   </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on

  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/my.domain.com.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/my.domain.com.key

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

    SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
        SSLHonorCipherOrder On
        SSLCompression off
        # Add six earth month HSTS header for all users...
        # Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000"
        # If you want to protect all subdomains, use the following header
        # ALL subdomains HAVE TO support HTTPS if you use this!
        # Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000 ; includeSubDomains
        SSLCipherSuite 'EDH+CAMELLIA:EDH+aRSA:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH:+CAMELLIA256:+AES256:+CAMELLIA128:+AES128:+SSLv3:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!DSS:!RC4:!SEED:!ECDSA:CAMELLIA256-SHA:AES256-SHA:CAMELLIA128-SHA:AES128-SHA'
</VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
```

My problem is Apache is *always* responding with 301 when the request comes via the 1025 port. *BUT* If i disable the SSL on port 1025 and serve on clear http, everything works properly... I'm baffled!

I would much appreciate your help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

my .htaccess was messing it all up, I had to remove

RewriteEngine On

## RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80

## RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://my.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]